# Height, Time of the Ball

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The height $h$ in feet of a baseball hit $3$ feet above the ground is given by $h=3+75t-16t²$ where $t$ is the time in seconds.

**a.** Find the height of the ball after two seconds

**b.** Find the time where the ball hits the ground in the field

**c.** What is the maximum height of the ball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a.** Find the height of the ball after two seconds:

Set $t=2$, so $h=3+75t-16t=3+75(2)-16(2)^2=\color{#180}{89}$ feet.

**b.** Find the time where the ball hits the ground in the field:

Solve for $t$ such that $h=0$ as the height above the ground will be zero at the point of impact, so $0=3+75t-16t² \implies t=\color{#180}{4.73}$ seconds.

**c.** What is the maximum height of the ball?:

Differentiate the expression for $h$ with respect to time and set it equal to zero to find the stationary points (which are maximums or minimums) $\frac{\mathrm{d}h}{\mathrm{d}t}=75-32t=0 \implies t=2.34375$ seconds. Now substitute this value into the expression for $h$ such that $h(2.34375)=\color{#180}{90.9}$ feet, which is the maximum height. We note that the second derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d^2}h}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=-32 \lt 0$. So the stationary point is indeed a maximum (and not a minimum).

Answer (score 2):

Hints :

- a) replace t by 2 and evaluate h
- b) replace h by 0 and find the value of t
- c) find the vertex of the parabola.